# Update disconnected ADO recordset ID field with new ID

Tags: vb6, ado

Updating an old VB6 app using ADO and disconnected recordsets.  Works just fine except there are some old ADODC objects I'm also updating to use disconnected recordsets.  I've written code to insert new records and return the new ID value which is great.

However, when I try to update the current new record (in the recordset via .AddNew), I get "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."

I can update other columns just fine.  Just not the SQL identity column in the recordset.  All I want is for subsequent references to that column to now have the correct information.

The searches on that error seem to indicate that it's possible to update the value, but I've tried CVar(newID), just newID and nothing seems to work.

The Recordset is set as

```
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
```

I could hack each instance to somehow reload the entire recordset with the new object, but that seems like a lot of workaround.  In most cases, the newid never gets used until it's reloaded.  But I'm trying to replicate the action of a connected ADODC which would save the record and refresh itself with the new id.

Any options?

Comment: Hmmm... adOpenStatic means read only... you should try adOpenKeySet or adOpenDynamic.

Comment: Thanks @EddiGordo but unfortunately adOpenStatic is the only option for client side, disconnected recordset.

Comment: I also have a large VB6 app where I do the same thing you're attempting to do.  I don't have any issues updating the Identity column in the recordset.  The only difference I see is my LockType is `adLockBatchOptimistic`.

Comment: @BrianMStafford - Was hoping that would work... Same issue: "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."

Are you also adOpenStatic and setting the ActiveConnection to nothing post load?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly the same configuration as you.

Comment: @BrianMStafford - Wow... mystery then.  There has GOT to be a way...

Comment: @BrianMStafford - What connection string are you using (not specific details, but structure).  Provider or Driver?

Comment: Our connection string is `Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=<ds>; Initial Catalog=<ic>;uid=<uid>;pwd=<pwd>;`

Comment: @BrianMStafford - Thanks... tried switching to that... The error message is due to the ID column having schema rules.  The status of the field after attempting the change is "adFieldSchemaViolation" which "Indicates that the value violated the data source schema constraint for the field."  In this case, it's a SQL Identity column with values auto generated.  So even though I'm disconnected from the database, the constraints are loaded and in place and prevent me from changing the value...